# Android tabhost with onTabChangedListener not firing

Tags: android, user-interface, tabs

I have a tabhost where I need to use onTabChanged listener, but it does not fire. I have 2 tabs, each one of them uses an activity. Some said it's because they both use activities, and once they are started the tab event won't be called again. Is that so?

Comment: If they are in focus, they may not fire.  Code?

Comment: That was the problem. But thats weird enough, everytime i clicked one, every tab would be as focused. I needed to unfocus them individually.

Comment: @tkcsam you should post this as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are in focus, they may not fire.  Can we see some code to be sure?

Comment: I'd post the code but I already fixed.. basically what I did was request focus on the first tab, in the onCreate method. Then everything went as expected.